# Call something automatically when creating an object

Tags: java, class, object, instance

I want to show the message "Object number 1", "Object number 2", etc... each time that an object is created.

I'm a beginner in programmation so I just want to know if this is correct (despite the fact that it works) :

```
public class Test {

public static void main (String [] args) {

    Point pt1 = new Point();
    Point pt2 = new Point();
   }
}

class Point {
private static int nb = 0;

   {
    ++nb;
    System.out.println("Object number : " + nb);
   }
}
```

Comment: replace that `{ ... }` stuff with `public Point() { ... }`. One's a static block which is called when the class is loaded (I think), and the other's called when an instance of the class is instantiated.

Comment: Code is "correct" if it compiles and runs and meets your requirements.  On  the day that it does not you should fix it until it does.  There is no right way to do anything.  Please proceed.

Comment: checkout constructors in java . that might help

Comment: You chose to use a static initializer.  That's fine, but a constructor is the way to go.

Comment: moving forward post your porgram in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and get it reviewed.

Comment: Despite the previous comments, this is not a *static* initialiser block, but a regular (instance) initialiser block. It will be run for every instance much like the constructor.  A static initialiser block looks like `static { ... }`

Comment: @RobCo Yes you are right about that, but he said I am a beginner to programming so it whould be better to show him the natural way of doing things and OOP purpose of using constructors.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies !! It was a simple question but I've learned a lot of things. I still however have some difficulties to clearly understand the difference between { ... } and public Point() { ... } in this case since the two make the same thing (I'm trying to find an example when the use of the one instead of the other can become a problem) but I've perfectly understood the concept of constructors. Thank you again.

Comment: @Rodric People generally never use the regular initializers. _They're so rarely used that half of us here didn't even know what they were_. Constructors let you add extra parameters so you can do things like `Point p = new Point(10, 20);` (Use constructors!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct the way you are using the `static` variable.

Just move the code that increments and prints it to the class constructor instead of using an initialization block.

Because in OOP a class constructor is what get called when a new instance of the class is created, so that's the most appropriate place to put similar code that needs to be executed when we create a new instance.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Point pt1 = new Point();
    Point pt2 = new Point();
  }
}

class Point {
  private static int nb = 0;

  public Point() {
    System.out.println("Object number : " + (++nb));
  }
}
```

If you take a look at [**Providing Constructors for Your Classes**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) you can see that:

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint.

Comment: @vhula He said I am a beginner, so he's just worrying about the instanciation fact.

Comment: @vhula Since when was thread-safety a requirement? If it's necessary, then use an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: perfect example of use of static keyword with variable :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code into a constructor. Like this:

```
class Point
{

private static int nb = 0;

   public Point()
   {
    ++nb;
    System.out.println("Object number : " + nb);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will actually work. When creating a block inside the class, this code will be executed before the constructor is invoced.

```
public class Point{
    {
        //invoked before constructor
    }
    public Point() {
        //Constructor code
    }
}
```

When you have no constructor or only one constructor, it is more readable to put this code inside the constructor:

```
public Point() {
    System.out.println("Object number : " + ++nb);
}
```

Other people who read your code will thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put these 2 lines in a constructor.

```
++nb;
    System.out.println("Object number : " + nb);
```

If you need to an executable code in your java program It must an should be in a constructor or in a method.

```
public class Test {

public static void main (String [] args) {

    Point pt1 = new Point();
    Point pt2 = new Point();
   }
}

class Point {
private static int nb = 0;
public Point()
   {
    ++nb;
    System.out.println("Object number : " + nb);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not threadsafe:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.range(1, 100).parallel().forEach(i -> new Point());

    }
}

class Point {
    private static int nb = 0;

    public Point() {
        ++nb;
        System.out.println("Object number : " + nb);
    }
}
```

It can produce same "id" several times